# How to determine if a ViewController is top level or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a tab bar driven app.

The app has some view controllers that are stacked on each other the usual way. 
Some of these view controllers may be top level - meaning instantiated directly from the tab bar controller. Those do not have a "back" button in their navigation bar.

Some of these can be called at many points within the call stack. Meaning they could be called from some other view controller and not directly from the tab bar.

I am looking for a smart way to determine programatically whether the current view controller currently has a "back" button in its nav bar or not. 
(If it does not then I want to display some other bar item at that place.)

Any hint is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... from what you are describing, I can understand that you have a `UITabBarController` with a list of view controller in each tab, and each view controller is a navigation controller, which further leads to new views. And you are interested in finding if a particular view is the first view or the second view, and so forth.

Interestingly, there is a way to do this. The navigation controller is basically a `viewController` array with views added to the index of the navigationController. The first view will be in index 0. If you perform a `pushViewController`, the `newViewController` is placed at index 1.

Just check for the index count of the `self.navigationController` of that particular view. If it is greater than 1, you can be certain that it is not the initial view.

You can also check for the `backBarButtonItem` property, but then again, it may not be needed. The `viewControllers` array count should do.

Comment: Hi legolas and jemmons, the index count on the view controller's stack sounds reasonable. I will try thand and will find the answer to the next quesion myself. However, you may know out of the top of your head. Considering that there is a UITabBarController on the very top, would you expect that the index for each view controller on of each tab's stack is 0 or 1? Thanks so far.

Comment: The tabBarController is the `rootViewController`. When you use a navigationController, each view is internally assigned to each index position of the stack. This is a property of the navigationController, which you embed in each tab of your view. This has nothing to do with the `tabBarController`.

Answer (score 3):

You could ask your view controller for it's `-navigationController`, ask the navigation controller for its `-viewControllers` stack, and see what the `-count` of that stack is.

The currently-showing view controller is the "last" item in the stack (index *n*-1). The "back" view controller second-to-last (*n*-2 — *n* being the count of the stack). So if the count of the stack is 1, that means you've reached the top. There's nothing in the stack to go back to and no back button will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Consider just getting the index of the view controller within the navigation controller's `viewControllers` array property. If it's zero, then the view controller is the top controller (without a back button).

Answer (score 0):

[UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has topViewController and visibleViewController properties which could help you out. If you just want to know if there is a back button or not you can check the backBarButtonItem property of the [UINavigationItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html) and see if it is non-nil and non-hidden.

Comment: Though comparing `topViewController` and `visibleViewController` won't necessarily let you know if you're at the top of the stack if the view controller on the top appears multiple times in the stack.

Comment: You can not add the same UIViewController object to the stack multiple times (if you try you'll get a crash, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083124/iphone-pushing-the-same-view-controller-instance-more-than-once-is-not-suppor). You can add multiple *instances* of the *same* UIViewController subclass. So if topViewController == visibleViewController then the visibleViewController is at the top.

Comment: Well, yes, if there were the same view controller on that stack twice then it were two (or moer) instances of the same view controller class but not the same view controller object. So far that is clear. However, my understanding is, that the tab bar's view controller is on top of that stack. Is that correct?  --- Checking on the existance of the navigation item that corresponds to the back button sounds reasonable.