# Unexplained crash: NSInvalidArgumentException, same view controller instance pushed more than once

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm seeing an unexplained crash on my iOS app built with SwiftUI. It only affects some users, and I can't manage to reproduce locally.

Here is the stack trace:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException

<_TtGC7SwiftUI41StyleContextSplitViewNavigationControllerVS_19SidebarStyleContext_: 0x110859800>
is pushing the same view controller instance(<_TtGC7SwiftUI41StyleContextSplitViewNavigationControllerVS_14NoStyleContext_: 0x11088a400>)
more than once which is not supported and is most likely an error in the application : `com.myapp`


Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1893a186c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19e3bcc50 objc_exception_throw
2  UIKitCore                      0x18b575514 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:]
3  UIKitCore                      0x18b5751f4 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x18b6047c8 __45-[UISplitViewControllerPanelImpl showColumn:]_block_invoke
5  UIKitCore                      0x18b57eda8 -[UINavigationController _executeSplitViewControllerActions:]
6  UIKitCore                      0x18b6045bc -[UISplitViewControllerPanelImpl showColumn:]
7  UIKitCore                      0x18b5e4c54 -[UISplitViewController showColumn:]
8  SwiftUI                        0x1903784f4 closure #1 in closure #1 in NavigationBridge_PhoneTV.push(_:onto:animated:)
9  SwiftUI                        0x19042728c thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> ()
10 UIKitCore                      0x18c23f544 -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run]
11 UIKitCore                      0x18bd6700c _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks
12 UIKitCore                      0x18bd559a0 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks
13 UIKitCore                      0x18bd89bb4 _afterCACommitHandler
14 CoreFoundation                 0x18931c358 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1893165c4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
16 CoreFoundation                 0x189316b74 __CFRunLoopRun
17 CoreFoundation                 0x18931621c CFRunLoopRunSpecific
18 GraphicsServices               0x1a0ee2784 GSEventRunModal
19 UIKitCore                      0x18bd56ee8 -[UIApplication _run]
20 UIKitCore                      0x18bd5c75c UIApplicationMain
21 MYAPP                          0x100dbecc0 main + 7 (PushupsMode.swift:7)
22 libdyld.dylib                  0x188fd66b0 start
```

Looking at `PushupsMode.swift:7` it seems completely unrelated:

```swift
import Foundation

extension WorkoutModel {
    mutating func startPushups() {
        var pushupsCount = 10 + p.intensityOptionPicked * 10
        
        if(round > 6 || round < 3) { // <<--- this is the line crashing
            pushupsCount = Int(pushupsCount / 2)
        }

        // More code after that point
    }
}
```

The round variable is defined in another file, but there's nothing really significant around it:

```swift
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct WorkoutModel: Identifiable {
    // bunch of stuff before
    var round: Int = -1
    // bunch of stuff after
}
```

Obviously looking at the error message, it seems like something is getting pushed twice... however since I'm using SwiftUI I'm not entirely sure how I could have even done that.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: I'd be curious about where `round` is declared.  Since It seems to be crashing on an innocuous-looking line, I'd investigate why that line in particular is a problem.  Maybe there are threading issues with the multiple controllers?  Though I don't know why there would be multiple pushes.

Comment: Is there a business logic that you subscribed to (waiting) something, then based on that you are navigating.. So this code block may be notified more than needed ?

Comment: @user212514 I've updated the question, but the whole file is not related to pushing views

Comment: @EnesKaraosman The `if(round > 6 || round < 3) ` is actually not even supposed to be called at that point if I'm following what's in crashlytics. It's a "mode" that is not used for the situation that caused the crash.

Comment: Can you see in your crashlogs if it is related to a specific iOS version?

Comment: Also, did you try debugging it by triggering multiple segues in quick succession (e.g. double-tap on cell)?

Comment: @de.I tried tapping quickly both in the simulator & on device. I don't see anything specific to an iOS version (happens on 13 & 14)

Comment: I think the sidebar was pushed twice to the stack. Not that the WorkoutModel is the real thing that threw the issue. I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993344/nsinvalidargumentexception-pushing-the-same-view-controller-instance-more-than) and [pushing same view twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083124/pushing-the-same-view-controller-instance-more-than-once-is-not-supported-exce/10584277) which might give some ideas on how to correct

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that you are defining pushupsCount as an `Int(` on `PushupsMode.swift:8` which is causing the exception on `:7` from `:8` failing pre-execution. Try defining it as `pushupsCount = Int pushupsCount / 2` .

Answer (score 0):

Using `pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate` is not a good idea because `pushViewController:animated` will be calling on this undocumented method. Rather than changing transition this way you can use other documented methods for changing animation. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215672/how-to-change-the-push-and-pop-animations-in-a-navigation-based-app) might be helpful for you. You will also need to add guard in `pushViewController:animated` and will also need to set `transition.duration`. Calling `pushViewController` again and again is perhaps causing crash of app.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused when you place your navigationLink inside of a List with observed data.

**How to fix :**

Remove NavigationLink from inside of the list and place it outside.