# Can't display on the screen, Xcode6.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

So I was searching for the all day long and I fixed some but still, I can't display. So, here is the deal:

I have started writing Xcode for 3 days, and I am following the lectures of Stanford, online, so the codes look like the lecture codes. Although nearly the everthing is same with the lecture codes, my code can't display the words taken from the internet. The purpose is to build a dictionary and I will move on writing if I will be able to see the words on my simulation device, iPhone 6.

What I can't understand is, I send a message to window and said it to take navigation controller, in which I pushed WordListViewController (You can see that in below code, in the AppDelegate.m segment).

You can find my code below:

WordListTableViewController.h

```
//
//  WordListTableViewController.h
//  Vocabulous
//
//  Created by user30357 on 6/19/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 user30357. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WordListTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSMutableDictionary *words;
    NSArray *sections;
}

@end
```

WordListTableViewController.m

```
//
//  WordListTableViewController.m
//  Vocabulous
//
//  Created by user30357 on 6/19/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 user30357. All rights reserved.
//

#import "WordListTableViewController.h"

@interface WordListTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *words;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *sections;
@end

@implementation WordListTableViewController

@synthesize words, sections;

- (NSMutableDictionary *) words{
    if(!words){
        NSURL *wordsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cs193p.stanford.edu/vocabwords.txt"];
        words = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:wordsURL] retain];
    }
    return words;
}

- (NSArray *) sections{
    if(!sections){
        sections = [[[self.words allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)] retain];
    }
    return sections;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc{
    [words release];
    [sections release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return self.sections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSArray *wordsInSection = [self.words objectForKey:[self.sections objectAtIndex:section]];
    return wordsInSection.count;
}

- (NSString *) wordAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath{
    NSArray *wordsInSection = [self.words objectForKey:[self.sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    return [wordsInSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *identifier = @"WordListTableViewCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [self wordAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}


/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

AppDelegate.h

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  Vocabulous
//
//  Created by user30357 on 6/19/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 user30357. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  Vocabulous
//
//  Created by user30357 on 6/19/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 user30357. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "WordListTableViewController.h"
@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    WordListTableViewController *wltvc = [[WordListTableViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    [nav pushViewController:wltvc animated:NO];
    [wltvc release];
    [window addSubview:nav.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Those 4 all I have as classes. Furthermore, my storyboard has the class WordListTableViewController, since I deleted the ViewController.

Hope you can help me with the situation, because I'm really about to turn crazy!

Thanks from now!

Comment: Are you using storyboard ? in your storyboard have you given name to your view controller as WordListTableViewController ?

Comment: I'm not using storyboard, and Xcode6.1.1

Comment: You are not using storyboard then where are you creating UI ?

Comment: Doesn't it create with the codes in AppDelegate.m ? It may not be created, I don't know. I just thought, with code I will not need storyboard. A bit confused.

Comment: No, you are not creating. Please starts your development from here : http://www.appcoda.com/uitableview-tutorial-storyboard-xcode5/

Comment: Ok I'm reading right away. Thanks!

Comment: You can create your UI without using storyboard, I'm creating with code too. You are wrong about it @KamalSharma

Comment: @grhnkdlk I am not saying that we can't create , I am saying the code he wrote is not creating UI. Also I recommend him to use storyboard because it easy to start and will not puzzle like things to initialize and all.

Comment: I did with him recommended site! Thanks @KamalSharma very much! Also thanks you, who helped me guys!
However, I got still missing. My table doesn't show the indicator, which is written in the .m file of view

(cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;)

Comment: Okay, I have done with the indicator too ! Thanks for everyone !

Answer (score 1):

You are not initialize the window. This is my method to launch my project change it.

In **AppDelegate.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigator;
```

and `@synthesize` them.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    LoginViewController *controller=[[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    navigator = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navigator];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Gave me this error:
Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Comment: I'm sorry that I forget a piece of code to set window's root controller. Anyway I edited my answer

Comment: This time: Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported . 
Thanks a lot for your helping anyway!

Comment: ok I'm gonna give you my **didFinishLaunchingWithNoOptions** method change it with your project. It should work.

Comment: If you need more explainations I'm here to help you. You are welcome.

Comment: It keeps giving me the same error with even your working code. Like I wrote from lecture.

Comment: Did you delete your code and write just like my working code? also please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083124/pushing-the-same-view-controller-instance-more-than-once-is-not-supported-exce

Comment: Thanks a lot @grhnkdlk I'm done with the above solution, for some reason, mine is not working with code.